# Promises return in unpredictable fashion via $emit('fetch', resolve)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise

Sometimes `this.companies` will get updates, sometimes not:

`parent component`

```
   fetchCompanies (resolve) {
      this.$store.state.backend
        .get('/jobBuilder/company/all')
        .then(ret => {
          console.log('companies fetched')
          this.companies = ret.data
          if(resolve){
            resolve('resolved')
          }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
    }
```

`child component`

```
    toggleActivation (button, company) {
      button.disabled = true

      let fetch = new Promise((resolve) => this.$emit('fetch', resolve)) //which activated fetchCompanies in parent

      this.$store.state.backend
        .post('/admin/update-activation/company', {
              id: company.id,
              active: !company.active
        })
        .then(() => fetch)
        .catch(err => alert(err))
        .finally(() => button.disabled = false) 
    }
```

And I'm not sure why, but API calls are not in the order I need them to be:

```
companies fetched
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost/jobBuilder/company/all"
companies watch activated
resolved
XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/admin/update-activation/company"
```

where it actually should be:

```
XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/admin/update-activation/company"
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost/jobBuilder/company/all"
companies watch activated
companies fetched
resolved
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and why sometimes it works and sometimes not.

Comment: Move your `let fetch = new Promise((resolve) => this.$emit('fetch', resolve))` to your POST `.then(() => new Promise((resolve) => this.$emit('fetch', resolve))`. Didn't test this, but it should work. When you create `new Promise()`, `this.$emit(...)` will fire instantly, and you want it to fire after the post is done

Comment: Where did you get this pattern of passing `Promise.resolve` to another function? This is really not common. Why not just dispatch an action, in that action execute these calls in the order you need, and commit mutations as needed? The whole action can be wrapped in a promise so that you can catch()/finally() as needed.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky because I don't want to put it into Vuex if only one group of components are using it. Normally, I would use `dispatch` and it would work great, but I want to explore it it's possible to do it the other way.

Comment: @ljubadr your solution worked! Can I ask where do you know about callback as a second argument in `$emit()`?  There's nothing on this in docs

Comment: I just copied your code example :) Your second parameter for `$emit` is `resolve` and you have `fetchCompanies(resolve)`. You can find `$emit` api docs [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit) and scroll just a bit to __Using $emit with additional arguments__. Also there are docs for [Custom Events](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) and [Emitting a Value With an Event](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, which basically sends the callback as a parameter for the `fetch` event:

```
/**
 * @param {Object} button
 * @param {Object} company
 */
toggleActivation(button, company) {
    this.$emit('fetch', () => {
        // NOTE HERE: we wrap this call in its own function,
        // because if we do not, the promise gets executed and its result is sent.
        this.storeCompany(company);
    });
},
/**
 * @param {Object} company
 * @return {Promise}
 */
storeCompany(company) {
    return this.$store.state.backend
        .post('/admin/update-activation/company', {
              id: company.id,
              active: !company.active
        });
}
```

Then your parent component can do:

```
/**
 * @param {Function} after
 * @return {Promise}
 */
fetchCompanies(after) {
    return this.$store.state.backend
        .get('/jobBuilder/company/all')
        .then(after);
}
```

If you remember to make small manageable bits of code (like always returning a `Promise` from a function), you can make it more understandable and easier to chain them together.